# Java swing dispose() method

Tags: java, swing

I wanted to make a simple text editor (note pad) in java, but I have run into a weird bug that if you open a new file, close it, then go to close the original file, the close button doesnt work... the other buttons work... All I have in the ActionListener is

```
frame.dispose();
```

is there another way to do this?
EDIT: `System.exit(0);`

works for me

Comment: so it opens the new file on top of original file?

Comment: Yes and ok... (taking up minimum characters)

Comment: A somewhat unclear question in my mind as you seem to be assuming that we know about much of your program already. Please tell us more about your problem including more of the details.

Answer (score 2):

You may be confusing the functions *close file* with *close application* here. When you close a file, you simply want to clear your `JTextArea` (from [earlier edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/ff4e50d3-3138-4b64-abd5-d51c14b064d7/view-source)):

```
input.setText("");
```

When you call

```
frame.dispose();
```

the resources in the application's `JFrame` are no longer available. This should be used when exiting the application.